# Adding a class to past events using Fullcalendar with Google Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to change the color of the past events, I guess I need to add a class to them but that is the problem, how I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I did it (hard coding):

1. Before rendering:

   ```
   var hoy = new Date;// get today's date
   hoy = parseInt((hoy.getTime()) / 1000); //get today date in unix
   ```
2. When creating the html, inside the "for":

   ```
   unixevent = parseInt((event.end.getTime()) / 1000) //event date in Unix
   if (unixevent < hoy) {className += 'fc-passed ';} //add class if event is old
   ```
3. Add a new "fc-passed" class in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

it would be best to add the class to the "className" attribute of the event object
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Answer (score 0):

As per FullCalendar v1.6.4

Style past events in css:

```
.fc-past{background-color:red;}
```

Style future events in css:

```
.fc-future{background-color:red;}
```