# Change color of past events in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016044/adding-a-class-to-past-events-using-fullcalendar-with-google-calendar/4018216#4018216) to "grey out" past events in Fullcalendar, but I'm not having any luck. I'm not too well versed in Javascript, though, so I assume I'm making some dumb mistakes.

I've been putting the suggested code into fullcalendar.js, inside the call for daySegHTML(segs) around line 4587.

I added the first two lines at the end of the function's initial var list (Why not, I figured)—so something like this:

```
...
var leftCol;
var rightCol;
var left;
var right;
var skinCss;

var hoy = new Date;// get today's date
hoy = parseInt((hoy.getTime()) / 1000); //get today date in unix

var html = '';
...
```

Then, just below, I added the other two lines inside the loop:

```
for (i=0; i<segCnt; i++) {
    seg = segs[i];
    event = seg.event;
    classes = ['fc-event', 'fc-event-skin', 'fc-event-hori'];
    if (isEventDraggable(event)) {
        classes.push('fc-event-draggable');
    }

    unixevent = parseInt((event.end.getTime()) / 1000); //event date in Unix
    if (unixevent < hoy) {classes.push('fc-past');} //add class if event is old

    if (rtl) {
        if (seg.isStart) {
            classes.push('fc-corner-right');
        }
...
```

Running this code results in a rendered calendar with no events displayed and an error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of null

The "null" being referred to is, apparently, event.end.getTime(). But I'm not sure I understand what exactly is going wrong, or how things are being executed. As written, it seems like it should work. At this point in the code, from what I can tell, event.end contains a valid IETF timecode, but for some reason it's "not there" when I try to run it through getTime()?

This isn't a mission-critical tweak for me, but would still be nice—and I'd like to understand what's going on and what I'm doing wrong, as well! Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using FullCalendar2 with Google Calendar, you will need to use the version of the code below. This uses Moment.js to do some conversions, but since FC2 requires it, you'll be using it already.

```
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {                   
            var ntoday = new Date().getTime();
            var eventEnd = moment( event.end ).valueOf();
            var eventStart = moment( event.start ).valueOf();
            if (!event.end){
                if (eventStart < ntoday){
                    element.addClass("past-event");
                    element.children().addClass("past-event");
                }
            } else {
                if (eventEnd < ntoday){
                    element.addClass("past-event");
                    element.children().addClass("past-event");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works (using FullCal v.2.0.3). Thanks, Jaredatch.

Comment: @QuestionerNo27 Where would I add this code? Would it be in the eventSources?

Answer (score 3):

As per FullCalendar v1.6.4

Style past events in css:

```
.fc-past{background-color:red;}
```

Style future events in css:

```
.fc-future{background-color:red;}
```

Comment: Note that this styles the calendar days, not specifically the events.

Comment: FC5 has `.fc-day-past` and `.fc-event-past`

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to fiddle with fullcalendar.js. Just add a callback, like:

```
    eventRender: function(calev, elt, view) {
      if (calev.end.getTime() < sometime())
        elt.addClass("greyclass");
    },
```

you just have to define the correct CSS for .greyclass.

Comment: Awesome! I had tried working with a callback, but couldn't quite get the hang of the syntax. (Like I said, Javascript chops embarrassingly lacking!) — unfortunately, this (with an appropriate "sometime()" substitution, of course) is kicking out a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTime' of null" for some reason... As far as I can tell, it's not liking calev.end.getTime().

Comment: Yes, define the time/date comparison as you wish.

As for the calev.end being null, trace it with your debugger; it is supposed to be a property of the Event object:
[link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Comment: Ah—it looks like I was chasing a bit of a red herring. The first (of several) events on the calendar in question was an "all day" event, and so the calev.end property was apparently "null," which stopped further execution of the code. I'm pulling events from a Google calendar...is there something else I should use as a test to catch all day events that happen before "today"?

Comment: About your second answer:

By only adding a class to elt, you can set:
`.past .fc-event-title {color: gray;}`
(or for .fc-event-time, etc.) to style the event.

As for time checking, it is up to you what "past events" mean...

Comment: Ah, thanks—didn't catch the .fc-event-title—of course. I'd _like_ past events to mean "events that ended before today," but since the majority of events are all-day events, I may just have to be happy with the way I'm checking now.

Answer (score 1):

Every event has an ID associated with it. It is a good idea to maintain your own meta information on all events based on their ids. If you are getting the events popupated from a backend database, add a field to your table. What has worked best for me is to rely on callbacks only to get the event ids and then set/reset attributes fetched from my own data store. Just to give you some perspective, I am pasting below a section of my code snippet. The key is to target the `EventDAO` class for all your needs.

```
public class EventDAO
{
    //change the connection string as per your database connection.
    //private static string connectionString = "Data Source=ASHIT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amit;Integrated Security=True";

    //this method retrieves all events within range start-end
    public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end, long nParlorID)
    {
        List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();

        // your data access class instance
        clsAppointments objAppts = new clsAppointments();

        DataTable dt = objAppts.SelectAll( start, end);

        for(int i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            CalendarEvent cevent = new CalendarEvent();
            cevent.id = (int)Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]);

                .....            

            Int32 apptDuration = objAppts.GetDuration();    // minutes
            string staffName =  objAppts.GetStaffName();
            string eventDesc = objAppts.GetServiceName();
            cevent.title = eventDesc + ":" + staffName;

            cevent.description = "Staff name: " + staffName + ", Description: " + eventDesc;

            cevent.start = (DateTime)dt.Rows[i]["AppointmentDate"];


            cevent.end = (DateTime) cevent.start.AddMinutes(apptDuration);

            // set appropriate classNames based on whatever parameters you have.
            if (cevent.start < DateTime.Now)
            {
                cevent.className = "pastEventsClass";
            }
            .....

            events.Add(cevent);
        }
    }
}
```

The high level steps are as follows:

1. Add a property to your `cevent` class. Call it `className` or anything else you desire.
2. Fill it out in `EventDAO` class while getting all events. Use database or any other local store you maintain to get the meta information.
3. In your `jsonresponse.ashx`, retrieve the `className` and add it to the event returned.

Example snippet from `jsonresponse.ashx`:

```
return    "{" +
    "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
    "title: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "'," +
    "start:  " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString() + "," +
    "end: " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString() + "," +
    "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
    "className: '" + cevent.className + "'," +
    "description: '" + 
    HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "'" +  "},";
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from @MaxD The below code is what i used for colouring past events grey.

JS for fullcalendar pulling in Json

```
 events: '/json-feed.php',
 eventRender: function(event,element,view) {
         if (event.end < new Date().getTime())
          element.addClass("past-event");   
    },
 other options ....
```

'event.end' in my Json is a full date time '2017-10-10 10:00:00'

CSS

```
.past-event.fc-event, .past-event .fc-event-dot {
    background: #a7a7a7;
    border-color: #848484
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 eventDataTransform = (eventData) => {
       let newDate = new Date();
          if(new Date(newDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime() > eventData.start.getTime()){            
              eventData.color = "grey";        
          }else{
              eventData.color = "blue";    
          }
          return eventData;
      }
//color will change background color of event
//textColor to change the text color
```

Comment: Good answers usually provide an explanation along with any code to help give it context and explain how or why it solves a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's what I've got now, that's working (kind of):

```
eventRender: function(calev, elt, view) {
      var ntoday = new Date();
      if (calev.start.getTime() < ntoday.getTime()){
          elt.addClass("past");
          elt.children().addClass("past");
      }
}
```

In my stylesheet, I found I needed to restyle the outer and inner elements to change the color; thus the `elt.children().addclass` addition.

The only time check I could get to work, lacking an end time for all day events, was to look at the start time - but this is going to cause problems with multi-day events, obviously.

Is there another possible solution?

Comment: Hi, Please see my answer as this should help with multi day events.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from @Jeff original answer just simply check to see if an end date exists, if it does use it otherwise use the start date. There is an allDay key (true/false) but non allDay events can still be created without an end date so it will still throw an null error. Below code has worked for me.

```
eventRender: function(calev, elt, view) {
            var ntoday = new Date().getTime();
            if (!calev.end){
                if (calev.start.getTime() < ntoday){
                    elt.addClass("past");
                    elt.children().addClass("past");
                }
            } else {
                if (calev.end.getTime() < ntoday){
                    elt.addClass("past");
                    elt.children().addClass("past");
                }
            }
        }
```