# Full Calendar - How to distinguish past events and future events

Tags: coldfusion, fullcalendar, mura

I am having a hard time trying to remove past and future events that are not reflected by the current month. Currently this is what I have the following code below:

```
    <cffunction name="FullCalendar">

    <cfscript>

        var calendarid = $.getbean('content').loadby(title='Regal Events').getcontentid();


    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>           
                <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
                 <div id="UpcomingCal" class="calendarResize">
                 </div>
         <script>

         mura.loader()
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",{media:'all'})
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css",{media:'print'})
            .loadjs(
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/gcal.js",
                function(){
                     $('##RegalUpcomingCal').fullCalendar({
                         weekMode: 'liquid',
                         eventSources: [
                            {
                                url: '#variables.$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/proxy.cfc?calendarid=#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                , type: 'POST'
                                , data: {
                                    method: 'getFullCalendarItems'
                                    , calendarid: '#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                    , siteid: '#variables.$.content('siteid')#'
                                    , categoryid: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('categoryid'))#'
                                    , tag: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('tag'))#'
                                }
                                <!---, color: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].background#'
                                , textColor: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].text#'--->
                                , error: function() {
                                    $('##mura-calendar-error').show();
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    })
                }

               )
         </script>

        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

I was able to remove the dates but as it is generated, it does get ride of the structure of calendar which I am not sure why. However, I am not sure how to add the following code to be able to distinguish past and future events:

```
                            eventRender:function(event, tag){
    var ntoday = new Date().getTime();
    var eventEnd = moment( event.end ).valueOf();
var eventStart = moment( event.start ).valueOf();
if (!event.end){
     if (eventStart < ntoday){
        element.addClass("fc-content");
        element.children().addClass("fc-content");
     }
} else {
if (eventEnd < ntoday){
    element.addClass("fc-content");
    element.children().addClass("fc-content");
    }
```

}
}
and not sure where to add it in the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE

Currently I have the eventRender in my code but it still does not remove past or future events. what am I doing wrong?

```
<cffunction name="FullCalendar">

    <cfscript>

        var calendarid = $.getbean('content').loadby(title='Regal Events').getcontentid();


    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>           
                <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
                 <div id="UpcomingCal" class="calendarResize">
                 </div>
         <script>

         mura.loader()
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",{media:'all'})
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-custom.css",{media:'all'})
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css",{media:'print'})
            .loadjs(
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/gcal.js",
                function(){
                     $('##UpcomingCal').fullCalendar({
                         weekMode: 'liquid',
                         eventSources: [
                            {
                                url: '#variables.$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/proxy.cfc?calendarid=#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                , type: 'POST'
                                , data: {
                                    method: 'getFullCalendarItems'
                                    , calendarid: '#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                    , siteid: '#variables.$.content('siteid')#'
                                    , categoryid: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('categoryid'))#'
                                    , tag: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('tag'))#'
                                }
                                <!---, color: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].background#'
                                , textColor: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].text#'--->
                                , error: function() {
                                    $('##mura-calendar-error').show();
                                }
                                , eventRender:function(event, element, view){
                                    var ntoday = new Date().getTime();
                                    var eventEnd = moment( event.end ).valueOf();
                                    var eventStart = moment( event.start ).valueOf();
                                    if (!event.end){
                                    if (eventStart < ntoday){
                                        element.addClass("past-event");
                                        element.children().addClass("past-event");
                                    }
                                    } else {
                                        if (eventEnd < ntoday){
                                            element.addClass("past-event");
                                            element.children().addClass("past-event");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    });
                }

               )
         </script>

        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `eventRender` callback? [see: fullcalendar docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632229/change-color-of-past-events-in-fullcalendar) for an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @beloitdavisja I have tried it. What happen's is it will clear the calendar and I am not sure what I am doing wrong